# How to write the SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Suppose I have the following table, How can I write the SQL query to find a set of results which are the minimum c for each b? for example, I want (7, 45) and (16, 69) for the following table.

```
  a |      b | c 
-----+--------+----
  3 |      7 | 53
  2 |      7 | 49
  1 |      7 | 45
  5 |      7 | 61
 13 |     16 | 69
 15 |     16 | 77
  6 |      7 | 65
  4 |      7 | 57
 14 |     16 | 73
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Your problem is a very basic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT b, MIN(c)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `distinct on` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (b) b, c
from t
order by b, c asc;
```

An alternative is `group by`:

```
select b, min(c)
from t
group by b;
```

You can try both and see which is faster.